# Зависимость Path от pk

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Пытаю сделать path, который зависит от pk. Выдаёт ошибку при переходе на эту ссылку.
urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
import lessons.views as lessons

urlpatterns = [
    path('/<pk>', lessons.lessons_view, name='index'),
]
```

views.py

```
def lessons_view(request, pk = None):


    return render(request, 'templates/lessons/ocenki.html')
```

Ошибка
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Во-первых, какую ошибку? Во-вторых, что такое keker? [mcve]

Comment: Keker не влияет на это точно без него тоже не работает. Картинку добавил.

Comment: У вас в `return redirect('lessons:index')` не указан `pk` же

Comment: А как его нужно указать)?

Answer (score 0):

URL немного подправить надо:

```
path('<pk>/', lessons.lessons_view, name='index'),
```

В файле upload/views.py найти строку **return redirect('lessons:index')** и заменить на:

```
return redirect('lessons:index', pk=PRIMARY_KEY)
```

где PRIMARY_KEY - ключ, который нужно передать ссылке.

Также не забудьте заменить все перенаправления на этот путь в шаблонах/других view по примеру выше(если они есть).